# Service Desk calls reports - Report Implementation assistance using Pandas

Tags: pandas, implementation

From the dataframe below I need to get the following information per USER using Pandas:

- Total Number of calls per day (the csv report contains a month of calls per user)
- Total number of RONA calls per day (RignTime == 20 sec)
- Talk average time

My dataframe:

- The **Name** column contains every single SD analyst (25 - 30 in Total). On index[0] **USER1** first call is register and on index[10] you get the last call registered from **USER1** follow up at index[11] first call for **USER2** gets registered and on index[19] last call for **USER2** is registered, subsequently every single **USER** gets registered in the same process in the same column.

My planned solution (may not be "Best Practices"):

**NOTE:** I will need help with the implementation code of the descriptions below not the **"answer to everything"** but at least a good starting point so I can learn the process, think and solve. Thank you in advance.

- Store USER#, START_INDEX and END_INDEX on an immutable object e.g. tuple or else
- Create an ExtractUserData_Function() that contains a for loop that will:

  1. Iterate through a range index (START_INDEX, END_INDEX) from the **Name** column and save all rows and columns from the USER# to a new temporary dataframe.
  2. Other FUNCTIONS() will be applied to the temporary dataframe to extract data and save all to a new dataframe Main_Report
- Create different CALCULATE_DATA_FUNCTIONS() to extract the report information needed

|  | Name | DateTime | CallDispositionFlag | Duration | RingTime | TalkTime | HoldTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USER1 | 8/1/2023 8:54 | Requery | 0:00:21 | 0:00:20 | 0:00:00 | 0:00:00 |
| 1 | nan | 8/1/2023 9:12 | Handled | 0:07:32 | 0:00:04 | 0:04:21 | 0:00:00 |
| 2 | nan | 8/1/2023 9:35 | Handled | 0:09:00 | 0:00:02 | 0:03:11 | 0:00:00 |
| 3 | nan | 8/1/2023 9:41 | Handled | 0:03:18 | 0:00:09 | 0:02:17 | 0:00:00 |
| 4 | nan | 8/1/2023 9:59 | Short | 0:00:04 | 0:00:03 | 0:00:00 | 0:00:00 |
| 5 | nan | 8/1/2023 10:10 | Requery | 0:00:20 | 0:00:20 | 0:00:00 | 0:00:00 |
| 6 | nan | 8/1/2023 10:24 | Handled | 0:06:11 | 0:00:06 | 0:01:04 | 0:00:00 |
| 7 | nan | 8/1/2023 10:54 | Handled | 0:08:00 | 0:00:09 | 0:02:51 | 0:00:00 |
| 8 | nan | 8/1/2023 11:06 | Handled | 0:06:22 | 0:00:13 | 0:00:49 | 0:00:20 |
| 9 | nan | 8/1/2023 11:25 | Handled | 0:12:20 | 0:00:13 | 0:05:08 | 0:04:13 |
| 10 | USER1 | 8/1/2023 12:22 | Handled | 0:11:29 | 0:00:12 | 0:06:17 | 0:00:00 |
| 11 | USER2 | 8/1/2023 12:46 | Handled | 0:13:00 | 0:00:11 | 0:07:49 | 0:00:00 |
| 12 | nan | 8/1/2023 12:53 | Requery | 0:00:20 | 0:00:20 | 0:00:00 | 0:00:00 |
| 13 | nan | 8/1/2023 13:20 | Handled | 0:07:12 | 0:00:15 | 0:01:57 | 0:00:00 |
| 14 | nan | 8/1/2023 13:43 | Handled | 0:15:17 | 0:00:13 | 0:07:57 | 0:04:28 |
| 15 | nan | 8/1/2023 14:42 | Handled | 0:21:13 | 0:00:11 | 0:09:46 | 0:06:15 |
| 16 | nan | 8/1/2023 14:52 | Requery | 0:00:21 | 0:00:20 | 0:00:00 | 0:00:00 |
| 17 | nan | 8/1/2023 15:27 | Handled | 0:06:33 | 0:00:07 | 0:01:25 | 0:00:00 |
| 18 | nan | 8/1/2023 15:46 | Handled | 0:05:15 | 0:00:09 | 0:00:05 | 0:00:00 |
| 19 | USER2 | 8/1/2023 16:06 | Short | 0:00:15 | 0:00:00 | 0:00:00 | 0:00:00 |